# java rest webservice, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/server/spi/Container

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey

i am trying to run java rest webservice program. constantly i am getting this error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Injections.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injections.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl.<init>(RuntimeDelegateImpl.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:117)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:165)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:135)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:120)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.newInstance(UriBuilder.java:95)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    at co.test.RestClient.getBaseUri(RestClient.java:31)
    at co.test.RestClient.main(RestClient.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocatorFactory$CreatePolicy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
```

java classes are

Hello.java

```
package co.test;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayStringHello(){
        String Str="this is hello plain";
        return Str;
    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHTMLHello(){
        String Str="<html><title>title</title><body><h1>hello from html</h1></body></html>";
        return Str;
    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello(){
        String Str="<?xml version=\"1.0\"><title>title</title><body><h1>hello from html</h1></body>";
        return Str;
    }

}
```

RestClient.java

```
package co.test;

import java.net.URI;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;

public class RestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientConfig config= new ClientConfig();
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
         WebTarget target= client.target(RestClient.getBaseUri());

         String plain=target.path("rest").path("hello").request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);
         String html=target.path("rest").path("hello").request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).get(String.class);
         String xml=target.path("rest").path("hello").request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(String.class);

         System.out.println(plain);
         System.out.println(html);
         System.out.println(xml);

    }

    private static URI getBaseUri(){
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/RestWSDemo/").build();
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>RestWSDemo</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>JerseyRestService</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>co.test</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>JerseyRestService</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="rest/hello">Hello</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and the jar files i am using are:

[image: jars]

can anyone help me with this? thank you

Comment: Why do you use such an old version?

Comment: as told in answer,follow the steps, remove build from server, create a new build then try

Comment: thank you so much, finally it works